# CSS how to not use style

Tags: css, gwt, iframe, resize, popup

I do not do CSS, just now that is why I am having difficulty tweaking this.. I am having prob with my pop up that uses Iframe. In css there's style like this:

```
iframe {
    border:none;
    height:440px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
    **min-width:760px;**
    overflow:auto;
    width:98%;
}
```

it produces an html when page is viewed like this:

```
<div style="left: 404px; top: 75px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; overflow: visible; clip: rect(auto auto auto auto); " class="dialogPanel"><div class="">.....</div>
```

that's why no matter how I set the height in the code behind, it would not resize accordingly:

```
 profileFrame = new Frame(url);

        profileFrame.setHeight("350px");
        profileFrame.setWidth("450px");
        panel.add(profileFrame);

        content.add(panel);
```

but when I removed the min-width from the CSS iframe, it already resized to my wish.

Q: how do I not use the iframe style to this certain iframe of mine? I do not want to remove the min-width as this style is being used by all  iframes in the application.

I tried removing it by using   `profileFrame.removeStyleName("iframe")`,  I also tried all other removestyle methods available  but did not work.
Any suggestion pls? thanks

Comment: I believe to remember, that 'local' CSS beats 'page CSS', which beats 'included CSS'. That means, if you put the min-width into the iframe-tag and set it to '0', it might do the trick for you.

Comment: the tag is generated (programmatically) and not html layout from a page from solution so there is no way I can do that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a class to this iFrame so try

```
iframe .dialogPanel {
min-width: 0px;
}
```

this will make only iframes with the class "dialogPanel" have no min-width, and will leave the rest with their min-width